# Virtual methods still required when using Moq?

Tags: moq, virtual-functions

We're using Moq and I was wondering what the current role of `virtual` methods were in it-- in the post below dated 2008 it's clear you had to mark your methods as virtual in order for Moq to work (or inherit from an interface.)

[Moq discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/moqdisc/LgLjZ9AX8nQ)

However, is this still the case in .Net 4.5, that you're required to use `virutal` methods in the class you want to mock?  And does this also hold true when you create a wrapper class around a static method-- the wrapper class either inherits from an interface or the method in question needs to be marked `virtual`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hasn't changed in .NET 4 or 4.5. As the link you provided explains, Moq uses Castle Windsor [Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to generate a type derived from the type you wish to mock. Therefore, the standard rules of inheritance apply. The derived type generated by Moq can only intercept calls to methods that any normal derived class can override.